# Conditional with htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I am using this to take a special chars from the URL:

```
echo '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["concert"]);
```

and I need to create a conditional in order to put one title and one image depending on what is on this special chars from the URL.

So something like:

```
if htmlspecialchars "concert" == "fanpass" do this, else do this.
```

Any idea how can I put a conditional statement with this?

Comment: why not u'r using another get parameter to do this?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to use another GET to do this but I am not very sure about the correct way, I have tried different ways and is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a confusion in the use of the words *special chars*. In the meaning of the PHP function *htmlspecialchars*, a special character is a less-than symbol (<), a greater-than symbol (>), ampersand (&) and possibly a single or double quote.

You should not apply *htmlspecialchars* when comparing a string with another normal string.

So, why not just:

```
$concert = $_GET["concert"];
if ($concert === "fanpass") {
    // do one thing
} else if ($concert === "studentdiscount") {
    // do another thing
} else {
    // any other value
    echo htmlspecialchars($concert);
    // ...
}
```

Going by the variable names, it seems you want to use the *concert* parameter for something else, like a discount condition.

In that case you could start to use a new URL parameter, like for instance *rate*:

```
$concert = $_GET["concert"];
$rate = "(none)";
if (isset($_GET["discount"]) {
    $rate = $_GET["discount"];
};
if ($rate === "fanpass") {
    // do one thing
} else if ($rate === "studentdiscount") {
    // do another thing
} else {
    // any other value
    // ...
}
echo "Your concert: {htmlspecialchars($concert)}<br>";
echo "Your rate: {htmlspecialchars($rate)}<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I could solve this problem with your help!